# Regex Replace different kinds of single quotes

Tags: c#, mysql, regex

Those nasty single quotes that love to cause havoc in MySQL, seem to have cousins!!! We have a system where users will to job updates from clients, either pasting in content from emails, or copy and paste from almost anywhere, and every time we cater for one single quote, another pops up. Here are the different ones : `` ’ ´ ' ` `` <--

As my regex is pretty weak, my fellow developer said I should just remove them using:

```
return Regex.Replace(oldText, @"[’´'`""]", @"");
```

I don't like this, its unprofessional, removing all single quotes. What I want to do, as many forums suggest, is just double up the single quotes. Would this be correct?

```
return Regex.Replace(oldText, @"[’´'`""]", @"''");
```

this though is done, because in his DAL, he constructs his insert statements with single quotes:

```
sql.Append(",`to_complete_by`='" + obj.toCompleteBy + "'");
```

Would I be able to avoid this error by changing `^^` to this?

```
sql.Append(",`to_complete_by`=\"" + obj.toCompleteBy + "\"");
```

or regex replace a preferred method?

Comment: All methods you describe can and will be circumvented. Use prepared statements if you don't want to get owned.

Comment: why don't you simply use SqlParameters? Would save you from having to replace ANYTHING.

Comment: I was thinking about prepared statements, but for some reason we have to use mySql 4.01, luckily it seems like it does support it. Cause i agree, this is putting "plasters" on everything, and something else will pop up most probably. Not too clued up on SqlParameters though, i need to read up on that. Thanks guys ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you're working with an old version of MySQL that doesn't support prepared statements, you should at least take advantage of the fact that modern database interfaces can emulate such features of they aren't supported by the database itself. In your case it's not so much the potential performance gain, but the added security though separation of statement syntax and value representations.